# Bash/Sed - multiline sed operation printing lines out of order

Tags: bash, sed

I am having some trouble with using sed to edit a log file.  I have built it into a function which is supposed to replace the text between two search strings with the output from another function.  It is almost working correctly, but is printing the lines to the log file out of order.  For the life of me I can't figure out why, and most adjustments I have made while trying to fix it have actually had less desirable results.

My sed function:

```
log_edit(){
"$3" > temp.txt
sed -i -n "/$1/{
:loop
n
/$2/!b loop
x
r temp.txt
G
s/$2/\n\n&/
}
p" "$FILE"
rm temp.txt
}
```

I am using the "=== text ===" dividers as my start and stop strings to pass along to the function, and using the same functions that built the log in the first place to fill the temporary text file.
The problem is occurring somewhere near/related to the 'G' command.  Rather than appending the hold pattern line to the end of the string, it appears to be attaching it to the beginning of the string.

Original log sample/Desired output:

```
=== Metech ITAMS Log ===

Metech Recycling
ITAMS Hardware Report
Date: Thu Mar  2 08:01:38 PST 2017
Tech: SP

=== Manufacturer Information ===

# dmidecode 2.12
...
```

Unfortunately, the output I am getting looks like this:

```
=== Manufacturer Information ===

=== Metech ITAMS Log ===

Metech Recycling
ITAMS Hardware Report
Date: Fri Mar  3 09:39:02 PST 2017
Tech: SS

# dmidecode 2.12
...
```

Would someone be able to help me understand what I'm doing wrong, or propose a fix?  This is my first question ever to SO, if more information is necessary I am happy to provide it.  Thanks in advance.

Edit #1: As requested a snippet of the code that calls the function:

```
        2)
            printf "\n"
            text_prompt "Please enter Tech initials: "
            set_tech_id
            text_prompt "Please enter Traveler ID: "
            set_travel_id
            mv "$FILE" "$TRAVEL_ID $TECH_INITIALS"
            FILE="$TRAVEL_ID $TECH_INITIALS"
            log_edit "=== Metech ITAMS Log ===" \
"=== Manufacturer Information ===" "print_header" 
            unset TECH_INITIALS
            unset TRAVEL_ID
        ;;
```

This is part of a menu function, and it would be overkill to include the whole thing, just be aware that there will be several calls to log_edit with different start/stop strings (though all follow the === === pattern), but usually calling different functions to fill the temp.txt with.

Edit 2: For added clarity, I thought I should add the function being called with $3:

```
print_header(){ #Prints log header.
print_div "Metech ITAMS Log"
printf "Metech Recycling\nITAMS Hardware Report\nDate: $(date)\nTech: %s\n" \
"$TECH_INITIALS"
}
```

and print_header calls print_div:

```
print_div(){ #Prints a divider.  Required parameter: $1=Text for divider.
printf "\n=== %s ===\n\n" "$1"
}
```

Edit 3:  For question clarity, my issue is that the $2 string is being written to the log before the contents of temp.txt, rather then after.

Final Edit: A solution was found.  I thought I would post the working code below just in case it's helpful to others.  A big portion of my problem was a misunderstanding with how sed uses the 'r' command.  There's another part to this solution that came from the accepted answer that I still don't understand, and that is the substitute commands that add backslashes, this was key to making it work.  I don't know why it works, but it does.

```
log_edit() { #Works!!
"$3" > temp.txt
sed -i -n '/^'"$1"'$/ {
:loop
n
/^'"$2"'$/!b loop
i\
'"$(sed 's/\\/\\&/g;s/$/\\/' -- "temp.txt")"'

#Blank line terminates i command.
}
p' "$FILE"
rm temp.txt
}
```

Comment: Do you have your heart absolutely set on using `sed`?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42585989/edit) to also show the code that calls `log_edit`.  Thanks!

Comment: I am open to alternatives, as long as the general functionality remains the same.  It doesn't matter if it's sed/awk/perl to me as long as I can switch portions of my log with the results of new tests, and keeping the formatting intact.  Unfortunately, I do not know the language of AWK or perl yet.

Comment: cxw I could show that, but it is part of a much larger function that runs a menu system. What I will edit in is just a snippet of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `r` command copies out the file before the next *read*, not when it is evaluated, and does not modify pattern-space.  However the file can be inserted into the script as part of an `i` command:

```
log_edit() {
    sed -n '/^'"$1"'$/ {
        p
        :loop
        n
        /^'"$2"'$/!bloop
        i\
'"$("$3" | sed 's/^[[:space:]]/\\&/;s/\\/\\&/g;s/$/\\/')"'

        # The blank line above is part of the `i' command,
        # and appends a newline to the inserted text.
    }
    p' "$FILE" > "$FILE.mod" && mv -f -- "$FILE.mod" "$FILE"
}
```

The command-substitution `"$("$3" | sed '...')"` filters the output
of `$3` for use with `sed`'s `i` command.  The `i` command prints
a series of lines will all but the last ending with a `\`.

```
$ echo three | sed 'i\
> one\
> two
> '
one
two
three
```

Comment: This solution was throwing an error at first, but I was able to fix it by changing the reference to "$3" back to a temporary file solution.  This is a little bit closer than my own solution to the desired result, but it doesn't delete the old data the new data is supposed to overwrite.  I don't understand the purpose of the substitute command with the '"$(sed 's/\\/\\&/g;s/$/\\/' -- "$3")"' line.  Would you mind explaining it?

Comment: With a little bit of modification I was able to get this working to produce the desired output.  I'm still not sure how adding an additional backslash alters whether or not this is working, but it is working.  Thank you!

Comment: @makraiz I have improved the answer, and added an explanation as to the use of the `i` command.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like just a few things out of order there. Try this:

```
log_edit(){
"$3" > text.tmp
sed -i -n "/$1/{
r text.tmp
:loop
N
/$2/!b loop
s/.*\n/\n\n/g
}
p
" "$FILE"
rm text.tmp
}

print_header(){ #Prints log header.
    print_div "Metech ITAMS Log"
    printf "Metech Recycling\nITAMS Hardware Report\nDate: $(date)\nTech:%s" "$TECH_INITIALS"
}

print_div(){ #Prints a divider.  Required parameter: $1=Text for divider.
    printf "\n=== %s ===\n\n" "$1"
}

log_edit "=== Metech ITAMS Log ===" "=== Manufacturer Information ===" "print_header"
```

Comment: This causes an 'unterminated s command (char 70)', though the s command looks fine to me.

Comment: Interesting, I'm able to run this exact code and get the results you're looking for. I was trying to modify your solution to meet your needs, perhaps your version of sed or the shell you're running is a bit different than my own.

Comment: I'm almost certain it's some sort of issue related to this.  Somehow the solution containing a strange substitution command that basically adds additional '\' characters to any existing ones got this working, but I can't explain why.  My log doesn't actually contain any backslashes, so it must be modifying unseen newlines.  Why that would change the behavior of sed is a mystery to me.  I did post my working code as a 'final edit' to my question, if you wanted to see the solution that did end up working for me.  Thanks though, both of these answers got me looking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `csplit` program, which can divide a file up into sections according to a pattern:

```
csplit $3 "/\($1\|$2\)/" "{*}"
```

This means take file `$3`, and break it into files `xxNN` (where `NN` starts at `00` and goes up) according to sections demarcated by an unlimited number (`{*}`) of patterns `$1` OR `$2` (two alternate patterns, separated by `\|` and grouped by escaped parentheses). The demarcation lines will remain in the output.  You can then write ancillary code to delete the files you don't want.  You can also change the name of the output filename and pattern.

```
# cat foo
a
b
@
c
d
%
e
f
@
g
h
%
i
j
# csplit foo '/\(@\|%\)/' '{*}'
4
6
6
6
6
# more xx0*
::::::::::::::
xx00
::::::::::::::
a
b
::::::::::::::
xx01
::::::::::::::
@
c
d
::::::::::::::
xx02
::::::::::::::
%
e
f
::::::::::::::
xx03
::::::::::::::
@
g
h
::::::::::::::
xx04
::::::::::::::
%
i
j
```

Note: You'll need to tweak it if your demarcation lines can repeat/occur out of order.  This is very simple; the breaks occur at any point that one pattern OR the other is seen, regardless of order.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this appears to do the same thing as what I already had going with '$3 > temp.txt'.  The issue isn't the splitting, but rather the order in which the log is being reassembled.  I need the logs to stay in the same format they were in originally.   To add to clarity I'll edit my question to include the function being called in $3 (at least for this specific example).